# C program to solve polynomials issue

Tags: c

I have figured out the rest of the program and I don't have any errors/warnings but now my issue is I am getting the wrong answer from the input but I don't know why.

Relevant code:

```
int x;
float h;
printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%d", &x);
h= (3x+2)/(2x-4);
printf("The answer is: %.2f \n", h);
```

It's giving me a number that is rounded down. For example if I enter 5 it will return 2.00 when it should be returning 2.83.

Please help!

Edit: I am sorry I am a bit tired. I did write my equation for h as:

```
h= (3*x+2)/(2*x-4);
```

Comment: is `3x` and `2x` a typo or do you mean `2*x`?

Comment: `h= (3*x+2.0f)/(2*x-4);`

Comment: Yes it is. I'm sorry, I made the edit. Trying it now. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: You will want to check `x` is different than `2`, else you will have a **divide by 0** error.

Comment: Ahh I see. I will keep this in mind for the future. For my purposes the integer entered will be 5 so I don't have to worry about that yet but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid C code. You can't use implicit multiplication (`3x` must be `3 * x` and so on).

If you fix that, you need to make the arithmetic happen in `float` to get better precision. The easiest way is to just make one of the literals `float`:

```
const float h = (3.f * x + 2) / (2 * x - 4);
```

should do it.

Comment: For whatever reason this gave me an error so I'm positive I am not placing it in the right area. I used another poster's solution and it works now but thank you very much for the help. I truly appreciate it.   Edit: I wish I could post the entire code but I think I might be violating something if I do.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of implicit conversion. The variables h is of float type. But the / operator sees two integers it has to divide and hence returns an integer in the result which gets implicitly converted to a float. If you want float divisions, try making the two operands to the / floats

```
float x;
float h;
printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%f", &x);
h= (3*x+2)/(2*x-4);
printf("The answer is: %.2f \n", h);
```

OR

```
int x;
float h;
printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%d", &x);
h= ((float)3*x+2)/((float)2*x-4);
printf("The answer is: %.2f \n", h);
```